# jQuery: Inaccuracy with scrollLeft when scaled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scrollable container with links and thumbnails - scrollLeft to thumbnail depending on the link clicked which works fine, normally.

However, when I scale the main container with transform, scrollLeft scrolls to wrong position.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

```
scroll: function(){
  var chapterName = this.chapter.getAttribute('data-chapter');
  var thumbnail = $('.thumbnail-content[data-chapter="'+chapterName+'"]').parent();
  if ( !$(this.chapter).hasClass('active-chapter') ){
    $('.active-chapter').removeClass('active-chapter');
    $('#thumbnail-container').animate({
      'scrollLeft' : '+='+thumbnail.position().left
    },{
      duration : 400,
      easing : 'easeOutSine'
    });
    $(this.chapter).addClass('active-chapter');
  }
}

reScale: function() {
  var windowHeight = $(window).height() - 20;
  if (windowHeight <= 827) {
    $('#viewer-container').addClass('scale scale075');
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.scale075 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);  /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+ */
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.75);  /* Firefox 3.5+ */
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform: scale(0.75);  /* IE 9 */
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform: scale(0.75);  /* Opera 10.50-12.00 */
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: scale(0.75);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sadikyalcin/8b386prj/9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this if you know the scale in the script. 
I modded your fiddle to fix it and tried to fix your example code.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n9f96xkp/)

So when you transform to say 0.75 you set a variable to 0.75 then when you set the scrollLeft you multiply the thumbnail position with 1/scale

```
var scrollScale = 1;
```

...

```
scroll: function(){
  var chapterName = this.chapter.getAttribute('data-chapter');
  var thumbnail = $('.thumbnail-content[data-chapter="'+chapterName+'"]').parent();
  if ( !$(this.chapter).hasClass('active-chapter') ){
    $('.active-chapter').removeClass('active-chapter');
    $('#thumbnail-container').animate({
      'scrollLeft' : '+='+thumbnail.position().left * (1/scrollScale)
    },{
      duration : 400,
      easing : 'easeOutSine'
    });
    $(this.chapter).addClass('active-chapter');
  }
}

reScale: function() {
  var windowHeight = $(window).height() - 20;
  scrollScale = 1;
  if (windowHeight <= 827) {
    $('#viewer-container').addClass('scale scale075');
    scrollScale = 0.75;
  }
}
```

Hope that solves your problem or give you an idea how to solve it more dynamically.

So the reason for this is that position().left uses your transform when it recalculates position.. But scrollLeft dont check transform. so you recalculate position so they use the same scale.

Comment: I've checked the fiddle, it seems to be working. I'll have a go and will let you know :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#thumbnail-container').animate({
        'scrollLeft' : thumbnail[0].offsetLeft/*change here*/
      },{
        duration : 400,
        easing : 'easeOutSine'
      });
```

I think,in this ticket,it's better to use absolute position then relative position.
And then offsetLeft has no relation with transform,so everything work fine.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8b386prj/10/)

Comment: downvoted: Does not work. Try the fiddle. Only solves the first click. After that clicks dont go where expected.

Comment: Are u sure?I test it with fiddle also,just fine.https://jsfiddle.net/8b386prj/10/

Comment: You are correct my bad. I missed that you removed the '+='+  part. with that it did not work.seems my vote is locked until edit occurs.

Comment: :(,my reputations just fly

Comment: Much simpler - but would of better with a bit of explanation.